# using SVN in android

Tags: android, svn

i want to use svn in my android studio project. I tried using SVNKit, but it uses java.rmi.server.UID which isn't available on android, so it crashes. Does anyone know something?

What i want to do:
get Information about files/dirs in the repository
add folders to the repository
add files located on the phone to the repository

Comment: plz put logcat or screenshot

Comment: what for? the cause of the crash is obvious: it can't load the class java.rmi.server.UID
I'm looking for an alternative(or for a way to use my own UID-class, the source code is easily copied and works in android)